# Как выводить транскрипт звонков напротив ссылок в n8n?

Tags: конструктор

Есть ссылки со звонками, они переводятся через open ai и должны заполнятся в клетки напротив ссылок, но заполняются почему-то ниже, скрины прилагаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]